# python: Search for a word and read the value from a file

Tags: python

I would like to populate a dictionary by fetching the values associated with a tag.
For example: if I have these variables stored in the file as

NUM 0 OPERATION add DATA [0x1, 0x2]

How can I extract the values of NUM, OPERATION and DATA if the order of the tag's is not fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not programming service.

Comment: What do you try for doing that thing? update post with your code until moment

Comment: We need to see the code you are already trying to use to solve your programming problem.  That way we can assist with correcting it if it needs it.

Comment: I have to populate a dictionary based on the values extracted.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assure that the operation never contains a space you can do something like this with the built-in method [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> line.split(' ', 5)[1::2]
['0', 'add', '[0x1, 0x2]']
```

It splits the line in a list of parts that are separated by    and then returns every second entry of this list starting with the second.

Comment: Thanks Hannes. in the line.split(' ', 5), can I determine the maxsplit( 5 in this case) dynamically?

Comment: If your line is defined like this and always is true to this schema there is no need for determining it dynamically. If the schema can change I would instead suggest a more complicated regex parsing